# Heatmap with independent rows

Tags: r, shiny, echarts4r

How can I generate a heatmap in R with independent rows elegantly?  By independent, I mean that the x-axis labels are different for each row.

The below code creates two heat maps - the first takes the top two rows, the second uses the last two rows.  The values of x differ for each cell of the heat map.  I'd like to stack these heat maps so when the mouse hovers over the heat map cells, it shows a different value for x for each cell.  This is a simplified example, in practice I'll have tens of rows so I'm hoping the solution to be generalisable.

I don't mind a different charting package as long as I can access the cell being clicked and it shows the value of x and y on mouse hover.

```
library(echarts4r)

df <- data.frame(
  y = c(1, 1, 2, 2)
  , x = 1:4
  , val = c(0, 1, 0, 1)
)

e1 <- df[1:2, ] %>%
  e_charts(x) %>%
  e_heatmap(y, val) %>%
  e_tooltip() %>%
  e_grid(bottom = 0, top = 0)

e2 <- df[3:4, ] %>%
  e_charts(x) %>%
  e_heatmap(y, val) %>%
  e_tooltip() %>%
  e_grid(bottom = 0, top = 0)
```